# Custom shortcut to pause a QuickTime screen recording? + Pushbutton

Tags: quicktime, screen-recording

I am looking to record my screen using QuickTime on my Mac, but stopping a screen recording requires you to press
ALT then click the Pause symbol on the QuickTime window.

I would like to know if it is possible to create a custom keyboard shortcut,
and then run the command from a usb pushbutton.

So you'll push the physical button to pause, and the push to resume,

Not sure what USB/Bluetooth  pushbutton should I buy for this.

The Pause-resume button should work while any program is active
[image]